# SWI-Prolog stack limit exceeded with tiny problem space using clpfd

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd

I try to show a minimal example for this behaviour. This is the code I load:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

gcd(A, 0, A) :- !.
gcd(0, B, B) :- !.
gcd(A, B, C) :- A #> B, !, A1 #= A mod B, gcd(A1, B, C).
gcd(A, B, C) :- A #=< B, A1 #= B mod A, gcd(A1, A, C).

ncalc(N, X, Y) :-
    Y #=< N,
    X*X #= (Y),
    X #< Y,
    X #> 0,
    gcd(X, Y, 1).
```

Querying `ncalc(9, X, Y).` I get:

```
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
ERROR:   Stack sizes: local: 1Kb, global: 0.7Gb, trail: 9Kb
ERROR:   Stack depth: 1,548,057, last-call: 100%, Choice points: 5
ERROR:   In:
ERROR:     [1,548,057] clpfd:pop_queue(_176712142, <compound fast_slow/2>, 1)
ERROR:     [1,548,056] clpfd:pop_queue(_176712170)
ERROR:     [1,548,055] clpfd:fetch_propagator(_176712188)
ERROR:     [1,548,054] clpfd:do_queue
ERROR:     [1,548,052] clpfd:parse_clpfd('<garbage_collected>', _176712222)
ERROR:
ERROR: Use the --stack_limit=size[KMG] command line option or
ERROR: ?- set_prolog_flag(stack_limit, 2_147_483_648). to double the limit.
```

Querying `ncalc(8, X, Y).` immediatley returns `false.`. Querying `ncalc(9, 1, Y).` through `ncalc(9, 8, Y).` (all possible valid ranges for X) too. Why does it only work for the simpler cases? Is there a workaround for this? Thanks!

PS: I'm new to prolog and what I plan to do is more complex, but knowing a workaround for this I can probably adapt the solution.

Comment: You should **absolutely** avoid cuts when using clp(fd). Try to think in terms of **state** changing instead. Note, this comment most probably will not help you with your immediate problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Let's ignore programming style, see @Capelli's comment for that.)

The actual source of non-termination is due to a weakness in SWI's CLP(FD) system. Here is the actual culprit:

```
?- X in 2..3, Y in 4..9, Y mod X#=X1.
X in 2..3,
Y mod X#=X1,
Y in 4..9.
```

So the system is not capable of deducing any useful information for `X1`.  Contrast this to SICStus:

```
| ?- X in 2..3, Y in 4..9, Y mod X#=X1.
Y mod X#=X1,
X in 2..3,
Y in 4..9,
X1 in 0..2
```

Here SICStus deduced that `X1` must be within `0..2` and thus not negative. This in turn avoids the loop in question in the next inference.

You can help the system a bit by insisting on non-negative numbers and thus the module is always smaller than the operands.

`A1 #>= 0, A1 #=< B, A1 #=< A`

In the meantime fixed in [CLP(Z)](https://github.com/triska/clpz/commits/master).

Comment: Nice catch! library(clpfd) needs so much a manteiner. Time ago I spotted a test case where all_distinct performs ~15 times worse than all_different....

Comment: @CapelliC It was strange how two seemingly unrelated things roughly coincided in time. It was somehow a huge problem that SWI-Prolog is MIT instead of LGPL; at the same time, new work on libraries happens only for a commercial, closed-source Prolog implementation (source code license price "quoted on request" for commercial users).

Comment: @User9213: Sorry I don't understand very well your comment - do you refer to the problems in library(clpfd) or licensing ? AFAIK SWI-Prolog licensing currently is BSD. Markus Triska, the author of library(clpfd) and others, had chosen SICSTUS because the attributed vars interface is better tailored for the enhancements he's pursuing.

Comment: @CapelliC Yes, you are correct; the 2-clause BSD is similar to MIT license and I was confused. I understand the two things are not related, and this is why I find it strange. Don't try to understand _very well_ since it was just an off-hand remark (and don't feed the trolls I guess).